# Python3 emoji characters as unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, emoji

I have a string in python3 that has emojis in it and I want to treat the emojis as their unicode representation. I need to do some manipulation on the emoji in this format.

```
s = '  hello'
```

This treats each emoji as its own character such that `len(s) == 9` && `s[0] ==`

I want to be change the format of the string so that it is in unicode points such that

```
s = '  hello'
u = to_unicode(s)   # Some function to change the format.
print(u) # '\ud83d\ude2c \ud83d\ude0e hello'
u[0] == '\ud83d' and u[1] == '\ude2c'
len(u) == 11
```

Any thoughts on creating a function `to_unicode` that will take s and change it into u? I could be thinking about how strings/unicode works in python3 wrong so any help/corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: call it `as_surrogates()` instead of `to_unicode()` because `'\U0001f60e' == ''` i.e., `''`  is already a single Unicode codepoint. `'\ud83d\ude0e'` is a surrogate pair that is a deficient way to represent the same Unicode character. You might need it if some API does not understand non-BMP Unicode characters such as many emoji. Usually, you want the reverse i.e., convert surrogate pairs into their corresponding Unicode characters: `'\ud83d\ude0e'.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16') == '\U0001f60e'`

Comment: Yeah, `to_unicode()` is misleading. `as_surrogates()` makes more sense for this conversion between unicode types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code that will take any character that maps into two UTF-16 words and convert it to a hex sequence.

```
s = '\U0001f62c \U0001f60e hello'

def pairup(b):
    return [(b[i] << 8 | b[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(b), 2)]

def utf16(c):
    e = c.encode('utf_16_be')
    return ''.join(chr(x) for x in pairup(e))

u = ''.join(utf16(c) for c in s)
print(repr(u))
print(u[0] == '\ud83d' and u[1] == '\ude2c')
print(len(u))

'\ud83d\ude2c \ud83d\ude0e hello'
True
11
```

I thought this was going to be a no-brainer, but it turned out to be trickier than I expected. Especially since I didn't understand the problem properly the first time through.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why do you need it but here's how you could represent non-BMP Unicode characters as surrogate pairs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

def as_surrogates(astral):
    b = astral.group().encode('utf-16be')
    return ''.join([b[i:i+2].decode('utf-16be', 'surrogatepass')
                    for i in range(0, len(b), 2)])

s = '\U0001f62c \U0001f60e hello'
u = re.sub(r'[^\u0000-\uFFFF]+', as_surrogates, s)
print(ascii(u))
assert u.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16') == s
```

#### Output

```
'\ud83d\ude2c \ud83d\ude0e hello'
```